# can I get transit visa in UAE on arrival at the airport?

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, uae

i am from Pakistan and wish to travel from lahore to jeddah via uae along with my wife and son. 
can i get visa on arrival at the airport? 
Also tell me the visa fees

Comment: Any prior research?

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't explain whether transit visas are available on arrival. It only explains that you might not need one depending on the length of your connection and if you remain in the transit area.